# How do I use Svelte component lifecycle methods on StackBlitz?

Tags: svelte, stackblitz

How do I use component lifecycle methods and other Svelte functionality within a Svelte app created using StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/fork/svelte)?

Usually I would just import this sort of thing as an ES import:

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte'
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Svelte version on StackBlitz is v2, if you want to use it you can find the documentation [here](https://v2.svelte.dev/guide). But I would advice to look for a service that has v3, like [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte)